# Ansible aws_secret module returns "botocore and boto3 are required for aws_ssm lookup" despite both having been installed with pip

Tags: python, pip, ansible, boto3, aws-secrets-manager

I am running an Ansible playbook from Jenkins. The playbook is run as user `ubuntu` on the target host running `Ubuntu 20.04.2`. My `playbook.yml` file is:

```
---

- name: Test
  hosts: all
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
  pre_tasks:
    - name: Install boto3 and botocore with pip3 module
      pip:
        name:
        - boto3
        - botocore
        - ansible
        executable: /usr/bin/pip3

  tasks:
    - name: "Template file"
      template:
        src:.env
        dest: ".env"
        owner: ubuntu
        group: ubuntu
        mode: '0664'
```

And the `.env` file is:

```
TEST_VAR={{ lookup('aws_secret', 'test-secret') }}
```

The `aws_secret` [plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/amazon/aws/aws_secret_lookup.html) requires `boto3` and `botocore>=1.10.0`.

When the playbook runs I get:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i host.compute-1.amazonaws.com, --private-key /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxx/xxx.key -u ubuntu
PLAY [Test] ******************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
 ok: [host.compute-1.amazonaws.com][0m

TASK [Install boto3 and botocore with pip3 module] *****************************
 ok: [host.compute-1.amazonaws.com][0m

TASK [Template file] *****************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.errors.AnsibleError: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'aws_secret'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: botocore and boto3 are required for aws_ssm lookup.
```

If I add the `-vvv` flag to the playbook execution command and add this as a `pre_task` task after the installation of the boto3/botocore modules:

```
    - name: Check binaries and versions
      shell: |
        echo $PATH
        export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin
        echo $PATH
        which python3
        python3 --version
        which pip3
        pip3 --version
        which ansible
        ansible --version
        pip3 list | grep -e ansible -e boto
        python3 -c 'import botocore'
        python3 -c 'import boto3'
```

I get this stdout:

```
TASK [Install boto3 and botocore with pip3 module] *****************************
        "Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.18.36)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: botocore in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.21.36)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: ansible in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (4.5.0)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3) (0.10.0)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.6.0,>=0.5.0 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from boto3) (0.5.0)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.25.4 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from botocore) (1.25.8)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from botocore) (2.8.2)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: ansible-core<2.12,>=2.11.4 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ansible) (2.11.4)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore) (1.14.0)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: resolvelib<0.6.0,>=0.5.3 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ansible-core<2.12,>=2.11.4->ansible) (0.5.4)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ansible-core<2.12,>=2.11.4->ansible) (2.8)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: packaging in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from ansible-core<2.12,>=2.11.4->ansible) (21.0)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: jinja2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ansible-core<2.12,>=2.11.4->ansible) (2.10.1)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ansible-core<2.12,>=2.11.4->ansible) (5.3.1)",
        "Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from packaging->ansible-core<2.12,>=2.11.4->ansible) (2.4.7)"
TASK [Check binaries and versions] **********************************************************
        "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin",
        "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/home/ubuntu/.local/bin",
        "/usr/bin/python3",
        "Python 3.8.10",
        "/usr/bin/pip3",
        "pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)",
        "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/ansible",
        "ansible [core 2.11.4] ",
        "  config file = None",
        "  configured module search path = ['/home/ubuntu/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']",
        "  ansible python module location = /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ansible",
        "  ansible collection location = /home/ubuntu/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections",
        "  executable location = /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/ansible",
        "  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Jun  2 2021, 10:49:15) [GCC 9.4.0]",
        "  jinja version = 2.10.1",
        "  libyaml = True"
        "ansible                4.5.0               ",
        "ansible-core           2.11.4              ",
        "boto3                  1.18.36             ",
        "botocore               1.21.36             "
```

`boto3` and `botocore` are clearly both installed on the target host. Why is the `aws_secret` plugin telling me `botocore and boto3 are required for aws_ssm lookup`?

Comment: Lookups always run on the controller node i.e. localhost. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html

Comment: Like this? `.local/lib/aws/bin/python -m pip list|grep -i boto`

Answer (score 2):

As @Zeitounator stated, lookups execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine ([docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html)). So the solution was to install `botocore` and `boto3` via `pip` on the Jenkins server.

Comment: I'm not sure why but... pip3 install botocore boto3 did not fix my issue.
sudo pip3 install botocore boto3 did.

Answer (score 0):

If you have boto3 and botocore installed, but still get this error then it's probably this: you have both python2 and python3 installed. Ansible might be running under python3 but the `aws_secret` lookup is still using python2 for some reason. A terrible fix for me was `pip2 install boto3 botocore`. I'm looking for a better fix now. Ubuntu 18.04...

Comment: do a `cat $(which ansible-playbook)|egrep '^#!'' ` and `cat $(which pip)|egrep '^#!'` to see if this is the case